# Getting .htaccess file in WordPress Uploads folder to work with SSL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

The developer I am working with created an .htaccess file in the WordPress Uploads folder to prevent people from cutting and pasting a URL to access a library of (mostly PDF) documents. In order to view a document, a user has to click on a link (and to access the link they would need to log in).

The client wants the site to be protected with an SSL certificate which has been installed. But when viewing the site in secure mode, i.e., in HTTPS://, the documents give a 404 error message.

The developer tried a few things to the file but it did not work. Personally I tried editing "http" in the RewriteCond lines to "https" but that did not work either. If the .htaccess file is removed, the site works fine in https mode, but of course we then lose the file protection.

HTACCESS file (with actual site name removed):

```
# htaccess to disallow direct viewing of PDFs.
# 2014-12-08, 12:31:49
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on 
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subdomain.website.org/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?subdomain\.website\.org [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?subdomain\.website\.org.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|txt)$ - [F]
```

The developer suggested I look for a solution on StackOverflow. Any idea how we might be able to get this to work? Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: No. You are seeing the file in it entirety.

Comment: (I'm Tom's co-developer.) That htaccess code is the one in the /wp-contents/uploads/ directory. There is also one in the root directory - which is where we originally stored the rewriterule for HTTPS. I'm wondering if the problem has to do with the order of directives and the existence/placement of the "L"ast flag.